# Crystal Report: Merge multiples rows in 1

Tags: crystal-reports

I have data in following format, grouped by plant

```
Plant1 4500 PCS
Plant2  500 PCS
Plant3  100 PCs
```

I want it as follows:

```
Total Production:5100 PCS  Plant1:4500 PCS Plant2:500 PCS Plant3:100PCS
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your data table and how you want the report to appear

Answer (score 0):

You can use a crosstab to achieve this. Group columns by Plant, Sum number of PCS as your summarized field and check the `Row Totals on Left` option.